# Timestamp insert giving wrong value

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have an application that makes a simple insert:

this is my configuration from sequelize

```
const options = {
      operatorsAliases: false,
      dialect: tenants.db_username,
      host: tenants.db_host,
      logging: false,
      dialectOptions: {
        useUTC: true,
      },
      timezone: 'America/Sao_Paulo',
    };
    const databaseConfig = {
      db: {
        database: tenants.db_name,
        user: tenants.db_username,
        password: tenants.db_password,
        options,
        pool: {
          max: 5,
          min: 0,
          acquire: 30000,
          idle: 10000,
        },
      },
    };
```

When I insert i use log to take the command that is generated by Sequelize this is the command :

```
INSERT INTO "table_teste" ("action_id","action_lat","action_long","action_time","action_type","action_obs","createdAt","updatedAt","user_id") VALUES (DEFAULT,13123123,413134,'2019-09-09 16:40:31.000 -03:00','ENTRADA','','2019-09-09 16:41:13.237 -03:00','2019-09-09 16:41:13.237 -03:00',2) RETURNING *;
```

The time that shows here **2019-09-09 16:40:31.000** is correct, but when this run from the Postgres, my database is inserting a wrong time like this **2019-09-09 19:40:31+00**

A strange behavior just happening I managed to remove the time zone from select, and my log now show this

```
INSERT INTO "table_teste" ("action_id","action_lat","action_long","action_time","action_type","action_obs","createdAt","updatedAt","user_id") VALUES (DEFAULT,2311321233,12323,'2019-09-09 19:21:14.000','ENTRADA','','2019-09-09 19:21:15.683','2019-09-09 19:21:15.683',2) RETURNING *;
```

If I execute this from my SQL in Postgres pgadmin4 it works fine but if I use Sequelize they give me a wrong date why?

Comment: Are your timestamps stored as timestamp with time zone or timestamp without time zone?

Comment: Sequelize doesn't allow me to create a timestamp without timezone type in createdAt and updatedAt columns that are generated automatically.

I'm sending my date like this 2019-09-09 16:40:31

Comment: No one can help me?

Answer (score 0):

All `timestamp with time zone` values are displayed according to your session time zone, which is set with the `timezone` configuration parameter.

This value is also used to interpret a timestamp without time zone.

Since your session time zone seems to be `UTC` or equivalent, `2019-09-09 16:41:13.237 -03:00` is displayed as `2019-09-09 19:41:13.237 00:00`. That is fine, because that is the same timestamp.

PostgreSQL doesn't store the time zone with a `timestamp with time zone`: the value is interpreted and stored as absolute timestamp in UTC and converted to the proper session time zone upon display.